# Sum and Index match across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a range of different worksheets with the same format but different start dates. For example, see the image below:

[image]

I would like to sum up the income based on all the sheets that appear between two tabs. For example, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` will appear in-between the worksheets named `Portfolio >>>` and `<<< Portfolio`

If both ranges were on the same worksheet I could use Index Match to do this by adding the following in `C8`

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX($C$6:$H$6,MATCH(C8,$C$5:$H$5,0),0),IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$H$3,MATCH(C8,$C$2:$H$2,0)),0)))
```

Would it be possible to adapt this formula to sum across multiple worksheets that are in-between `Portfolio >>>` and `<<< Portfolio` tabs?

Comment: You tagged VBA, but the question indicates a formula. Is that intentional? Using INDIRECT would make it possible to solve this by formula, but if this is a large file it'll slow everything down, since it's volatile (recalculates on each change in the document). VBA would be a better solution, but than you should not request for a formula.

Comment: Your formula doesn't quite make sense - I'm assuming each tab is identical, but can't visualise what they look like.  They can't look like the current tab (i.e. your screenshot) because you're indexing off of a blank row 6 and row 3, which are empty in this screenshot - further, your (presumably 'total') row 8 doesn't reconcile to the sum of what appears to be in sheet 1 and sheet 2 for any of the months (from what I can see, month 1, row 8, income = month 1, sheet 1, so assuming sheet 2 income 0 for that month, even though you show it having 3052.60 income in 1st month [ 31 Dec '21].. ?

Comment: @Afikasky - does my soln not achieve desired approach? was it attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HIGH-LEVEL**

Ultimately, this can be achieved with something as simple as the following:

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!K2)
```

Although some setup is required to ensure the values / dates spanned are suitably located.

OneDrive link [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j961v4gOH9Pt5YHpHE?e=8i2DJ4) for a workbook demonstration of a working solution which can be generalised/customized as desired.

**SETUP**

- 4 sheets (overall, Sheets1-3, per screenshot) - data lies *somewhere* between columns A:H (doesn't matter where, but in in this case its assumed data lies above row 9 too for illustrative simplicity).  Also, this could be over Sheets1-2 per your example, or 1-100, so long as sheets lie side-by-side (ordering doesn't matter)

[image: Sheets: overall, 1-3]

(above can be easily customize to satisfy exact layout / span / range of cells in question)

[image: Flexibility to deal with data that can lie anywhere within a specified region in different sheets]

*(several steps could be omitted if these 2 rows simply occurred in same region of cells across Sheets1-3, e.g. always within A1:H2). However, the ensuing **steps** shall proceed on the above basis / setup, to ensure the soln. is adequately flexible to deal with a multitude of different layouts*

**3 STEPS**

1] Highlight / select the collection of desired 'adjacent' tabs (select left most, then  repeat: ctrl + shift + Page Down until right-most sheet (here, #3) selected / highlighted). In this case, region = J1:Q2 (available in all selected sheets):

[image: Selection of multiple sheets to manipulate all simultaneously]

2] In J1:J2, enter "Sheet", "Income" respectively (w/ apostrophes)

[image: Data locators: "Sheet" (for date range) and "Income" (for values to sum)]

*(red circle illustrates, this should now appear in J1:J2 across Sheets1:3)*

3] In K1, enter formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$H$9,MATCH("*"&$J$1:$J$2&"*",$A$1:$A$9,0),MATCH('Overall'!$B$1:$H$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$H$1,0))
```

[image: Obtaining data in common location across multiple sheets]

**IMPLEMENTATION**

In the overall sheet, all that's needed now is the following (per screenshot below).

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!K2)
```

[image: Sumifs reduced to sum eqn!]

This can be dragged to the right as req.

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like we have the following...

```
Sheet1, C1:H1 contains the dates, and C2:H2 contains their corresponding values

Sheet2, C1:H1 also contains the dates, and C2:H2 contains their corresponding values
```

And, on your results worksheet, we have the following...

```
C1:I1 contains all of the relevant dates
```

Accordingly, enter the following formula in C2, and copy across...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&{"Sheet1","Sheet2"}&"'!C1:H1"),C1,INDIRECT("'"&{"Sheet1","Sheet2"}&"'!C2:H2")))
```

You can add as many sheets as you desired.  Also, instead of hard coding the sheet names into the formula, you can enter the sheet names in a range of cells, and then refer to those cells.  For example, let M2 and M3 contain Sheet1 and Sheet2, respectively.  Then enter the following formula in C2, and copy across...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$M$2:$M$3&"'!C1:H1"),C1,INDIRECT("'"&$M$2:$M$3&"'!C2:H2")))
```

Comment: I would argue this is not robust enough.

Comment: @James  I would have to agree.  It's not robust enough, nor is it very efficient, since it uses the volatile function `INDIRECT`.

Comment: don't be too hard on yourself; you addressed the Q which arguably had too little info to begin with!  :)